# Oracle group multiple rows into one base on one column's value

Tags: oracle, group-by

Currently, I have 1 table with a structure like below (The ID column is the primary key):

```
ID                   Sub_ID    ACC_TYPE     ACC_NO    ACC_CCY    AMOUNT
----------------     ------    ----------   ------    --------   ------
KA31005493FC27XQ     DEF       MAIN_CR      1111      USD        100
KA31005493FC27XR     DEF       MAIN_DR      2222      EUR        200
KA31005493BC27XP     DEF       SA_MAIN_CR   3333      JPY        300
KA310054937C27XO     DEF       SA_MAIN_DR   4444      HKD        400
KA31005493KC27XZ     DEF       PNL_CR       5555      CNY        500
```

The values above do not have any rules, I just made it up for you to understand easily.

I want to select ACC_NO, ACC_CCY column of rows which has ACC_TYPE = MAIN_CR/ SA_MAIN_DR and put it to 1 row with columns name separated. Also with rows that have ACC_TYPE = SA_MAIN_CR/ MAIN_DR to 1 row.

And the AMOUNT_CR/ AMOUNT_DR column equal to AMOUNT of rows with the corresponding ACC_TYPE (MAIN_CR with SA_MAIN_CR to AMOUNT_CR, MAIN_DR with SA_MAIN_DR to AMOUNT_DR column).

Below is my expected output:

```
Sub_ID    ACC_NO_CR      ACC_CCY_CR    ACC_NO_DR    ACC_CCY_DR    AMOUNT_CR    AMOUNT_DR
------    ----------     ----------    ---------    ----------    ---------    ---------
DEF       1111           USD           4444         HKD           100          400
DEF       3333           JPY           2222         EUR           300          200
```

In case there have not been SA_MAIN_CR/ SA_MAIN_DR rows, the output should be:

```
Sub_ID    ACC_NO_CR      ACC_CCY_CR    ACC_NO_DR    ACC_CCY_DR    AMOUNT_CR    AMOUNT_DR
------    ----------     ----------    ---------    ----------    ---------    ---------
DEF       1111           USD           2222         EUR           100          200
```

Comment: I have provided a solution that works on 12.1 and later. But, your data in the post does not fully represent the actual scenario. I mean, do you have only MAIN_CR, MAIN_DR, SA_MAIN_CR and SA_MAIN_DR in your data ? And do your MAIN_CR, SA_MAIN_CR get created always first when compared to MAIN_DR and SA_MAIN_DR respectively ? And how many of such rows do you have in your data ? Please include the sample data with CREATE TABLE or SELECT statements like how I did. That would then be easy to try solutions.

Comment: @Ranagal Thank you for your reply. My ACC_TYPE column can have more values with no rules, and within 1 Sub_ID it must have at least MAIN_DR and MAIN_CR, the SA_MAIN_CR/ SA_MAIN_DR are optional. So, my expected result will have at least 1 row with the MAIN_CR/ MAIN_DR. And if there are SA_MAIN_CR/ SA_MAIN_DR with the same Sub_ID, there will be another row. I'm sorry to add this side question but if I want to pair MAIN_CR with SA_MAIN_DR into 1 row and MAIN_DR with SA_MAIN_CR into 1 row, what changes do I have to apply for your answer below?

Comment: Hi, I don't understand your requirement. Kindly post the sample inputs and expected output. I will write the solution for you.

Comment: @Ranagal I have edited the original post to specify my expected result, thanks again for your kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is possible.

To create the table of your data:

```
create table tab as
with inputs (ID,Sub_ID,ACC_TYPE,ACC_NO,ACC_CCY,AMOUNT) as
(
    select 1,'DEF','MAIN_CR',1111,'USD',100 from dual union all
    select 2,'DEF','MAIN_DR',2222,'EUR',200 from dual union all
    select 3,'DEF','SA_MAIN_CR',3333,'JPY',300 from dual union all
    select 4,'DEF','SA_MAIN_DR',4444,'HKD',400 from dual
)
select * from inputs;
```

Solution:

```
select  sub_id_general as sub_id, acc_no_cr, acc_ccy_cr, amount_cr, acc_no_dr, acc_ccy_dr, amount_dr 
from    tab
match_recognize
(
    order by id
    measures sub_id as sub_id_general,
             CR.acc_no as acc_no_cr,
             CR.acc_ccy as acc_ccy_cr,
             CR.amount as amount_cr,
             DR.acc_no as acc_no_dr,
             DR.acc_ccy as acc_ccy_dr,
             DR.amount as amount_dr
    pattern (CR DR)
    define  CR as acc_type in ('MAIN_CR','SA_MAIN_CR'),
            DR as acc_type in ('MAIN_DR','SA_MAIN_DR')
);
```

Output:

[image]